# A combinatorial problem - counting the solutions

Tags: co.combinatorics

Consider a square. There are 16 ways to paint its sides with two colors. 
For convenience, we will represent one color with a blank side, and the other - with a line drawn from the squares' center to the middle of the side.

Here are the 16 possible squares:

[image: Easy squares]

The problem is to count the ways to put them together in a 4x4 square, such that:

1. **Each** square is used **once**.
2. It is not permitted to rotate or reflect squares.
3. Each outgoing line must join another line.

   - Of course, it means no line is allowed to touch the square's border.

Here is an example of a valid solution:

[image: Easy solution]

I know, from a simple backtracker program I've written, that the number of valid solutions is 652. But can it be proven mathematically?

Actually, the problem I described is a "toy" version of the real problem: in addition to the *sides* of the square, consider also the *diagonals*. 
Here are the 256 possible squares:

[image: Hard squares]

How many solutions exist? Here, of course, we need to place all the squares in a 16x16 square, with limitations as above. I managed to get a not very tight upper bound of about $3.29 \times 10^{272}$, but I have no idea how to get the actual number.

**Edit:** Here is an example solution of the hard problem:

[image: Hard solution]

Comment: The construction of the problem seems to rely heavily on the "coincidence" $2^4=4^2$... :)

Comment: And then on $2^8 = 16 ^ 2$.

Comment: What exactly is the condition on the diagonals?  Each outgoing red line must touch *exactly* one other?  or *at least* one other?

Comment: This problem looks suspiciously like a special case of a $\#P$-complete problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp_P).

Comment: @Timothy, the outside border having no lines means some interior vertices will have at least three diagonal segments emanating from them.  I analyze the case that interior vertices each have 0 or 4 segments coming from them.

Comment: @Timothy, diagonals must continue to the next square. For example, a NW diagonal must meet a SE diagonal. Whether it has a SW or NE diagonal meeting it is absolutely unimportant (but the other diagonal must, of course, meet its match too).

Comment: @Geoffrey, yes, exactly. I tried expressing it as a SAT problem and running it through several #SAT solvers, but it was just too big.

Comment: Do you have a solution to the intermediate problem coming from $2^6 = 4^3$? i.e. paint the sides of cubes with two colours, then arrange the $64$ distinct cubes into one large cube with all outer faces the same colour.

Comment: @ZackWolske, good question! 
I'll try it out.

Comment: Your main question is the 4 dimensional version, colouring the 8 cubes of tesseracts, and stacking them into a $4\times4\times4\times4$ tesseract. I don't think it does much directly to rephrase it this way, but you might find some restrictions in the 3 dimensional case that carry over.

Comment: A slightly more natural question would be to ask for all solutions on the $4\times 4$ torus (respectively on the $16\times 16$ torus). There should be more but the problem has a larger symmetry group.

Comment: This is a good question but the title is too generic. I couldn't think of a concise version, but perhaps someone can come up with one and edit the title accordingly (the best I came up with was the somewhat awkward "How many ways can we arrange one of each type of these 2-colored square tiles into a larger square, respecting the colors?")

Comment: @ZackWolske, I'm trying the 4x4x4 cube right now, solving it as a #SAT problem. The binomial estimate on it is 11464426695775296878933868168565891023 ($1.1\times10^{37}$), so I think it would be possible to get an exact answer at least on that. The estimate on the tesseract is $2.77\times10^{207}$, only slightly smaller than the original problem.

Comment: @RolandBacher, the torus is an interesting idea as well! How many generalizations!..

Comment: @ZackWolske, the cube is still too hard for my computer, it seems. It worked for 8 hours with no result. 
The 4x4 torus was easier, of course. Here's something interesting: the binomial estimate for the torus was 165636900. The actual number of solutions: 203520. But as it's a torus, and symmetric under shifts, the "true" number of solutions is 203520/16=12720. 
Well, this is eerily close to sqrt(165636900)=12870. 
And the sqrt of the binomial estimate of the 4x4 square is 495, also close (or at least, not very far) to the true 652 solutions.

Comment: for the toy version, note 652 = 163 x 4, apparently there are 163 essentially different solutions, and the remaining ones are obtained by rotating the _whole 4 x 4_ square ... would that be right?

Answer (score 1):

The 4x4 problem is similar to labelling 16 of the interior 24 edges black with some
constraints: the top 3 edges must have at least one black edge, and the top 7 edges
have at most 68 admissible colorings.  I can't see a quick way to get 652, but showing
an upper bound of half a million follows from the observations above.

Using a similar analysis on the larger puzzle gives an upper bound of 
edge configurations of
$\binom{480}{256}$ which is less than $10^{150}$.  Another analysis of
the corners gives $\binom{225}{128}$; multiplying these together gives an
improved upper bound which is still weak.  It may be possible to improve
these bounds to below a googol,  but I don't see how yet.

Comment: The corner analysis assumes that a correct tiling induces a set of 128 vertices with four red corner lines emanating from each vertex.  The rules do not say whether other diagonal line configurations are allowed.

Comment: You can also have only two diagonals meeting at a corner - look at the example solution I added. 
My estimation went as follows: there are exactly 128 horizontal connections: pairs of tiles joined by a horizontal line. There are 240 places for such a connection, so $\binom {240} {128}$ possibilities. Same for verticals. 
For diagonals, again 128 for each of the two orientations, with 225 possible positions, $\binom {225} {128}$ possibilities. Multiply them all together and you get $3.29\times 10^{272}$.

Comment: Another approach for an upper bound is by a transfer-matrix method: Dropping the condition that all squares are different, one gets an upper bound $2^{24}$ for the baby case and $2^{930}$ for the hard case.

Comment: Indeed, but tighter bounds arise from coloring interior edges and points.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests a different approach to bounding the number of configurations.

E.umerate a sequence of partial configurations. Note that there are 32 choices
to place a block in the upper left corner. When that block is placed, there will
be 31 or 32 possibilities for a block directly below, giving some number  between
1020 and 990 for placing two blocks.  If we use this to count configurations which
have a third block placed just to the right of the first block, there will be roughly
31,000 possibilities, and definitely less than 2^15 possibilities.  Using computers, it
should be possible within a day to compute a sequence that counts the number
of partial configurations confined to an upper left triangular region of i blocks,
for i ranging from 1 to 7 or 8.  With that sequence, bolstered by a random
sampling of configurations and continuing a count starting from those, one
should be able to project a solution count that is closer to actual than the simple
bounds given above.  It can be shown that an upper bound is 32^i for i up to 8,
and the hope is to establish a better approximation through limited use of 
computational brute force.

Comment: Actually, there are only 8 choices for the upper-left corner, since the only lines permitted are Right, Down-Right and Down; the rest would touch the border and so are required to be empty.  Interesting approach...

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but similar examples for sharpening tools:

Consider all $2^6=64$ possible decorated regular triangles where
a decoration is a set of segments joining the center to some vertices
or to midpoints of some edges. Identifying such a triangle with its
opposite (through a central symmetry), one can try to tile 
the regular triangle obtained by inflating a standard regular
triangle by a factor $8$ with all $8^2=64$ possible forms (up to translation
and central symmetry).
The obvious compatibility requirement is: each decorating 
segment continues in a straight way at a vertex or at a midpoint.

I ignore whether there are solutions and how many but the complexity
of this problem is exactly between the original baby version (with 
$16$ squares) and the hard version (with $256$ squares).

Another intermediate problem is given by considering regular cubes:
joining the midpoint (barycenter) by segments to midpoints of a subset of faces
one has again $2^6=64$ different decorated cubes and one can
ask for tilings of the $4\times 4\times 4$ cube using all $64$
possible decorated cubes. (This non-planar version is of course
more difficult to visualize.)

This example can of course be generalized to higher dimensions:
The next case involves $256=4^4$ different decorated hypercubes
of dimension $4$. In the general case, we have $2^{2d}=4^d$
possible decorated $d-$dimensional hypercubes and we want 
to tile a $4\times 4\times\cdots \times 4$ hypercube of dimension $d$ using
all possible decorated hypercubes in a consistent way
(all decorations go on at midpoints of facets).

Comment: Sorry, I did not read all comments: The second suggestion is mainly Zack Wolske's comment.